# Array is subset of another array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, subset

In Spark, how to efficiently check if an array is contained in (is a subset of) another array?

Having this as example df, what could be the options?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', None]),
     (['a', 'b',None], ['a', None]),
     (['a', 'b',None], ['a']),
     (['a', 'b',None], [None]),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], None),
     (None, ['a']),
     (None, None),
     (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a']),
     (['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a']),
     (['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']),
     (['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a',None]),
     (['a', 'a',None], ['a', 'a', 'a']),
     (['a', 'a',None], ['a', 'a',None])],
    ['look_in', 'look_for'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forall`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.forall.html#pyspark.sql.functions.forall) can do the check for every element in the array in combination with [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains).

Spark 3.1:

```
df = df.withColumn('check', F.forall('look_for', lambda x: F.array_contains('look_in', x)))
```

Spark 3.0:

```
df = df.withColumn('check', F.expr("forall(look_for, x -> array_contains(look_in, x))"))
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+-----+
|     look_in|    look_for|check|
+------------+------------+-----+
|   [a, b, c]|         [a]| true|
|   [a, b, c]|         [d]|false|
|   [a, b, c]|      [a, b]| true|
|   [a, b, c]|      [c, d]|false|
|   [a, b, c]|   [a, b, c]| true|
|   [a, b, c]|   [a, null]| null|
|[a, b, null]|   [a, null]| null|
|[a, b, null]|         [a]| true|
|[a, b, null]|      [null]| null|
|   [a, b, c]|        null| null|
|        null|         [a]| null|
|        null|        null| null|
|   [a, b, c]|      [a, a]| true|
|   [a, a, a]|         [a]| true|
|   [a, a, a]|   [a, a, a]| true|
|   [a, a, a]|[a, a, null]| null|
|[a, a, null]|   [a, a, a]| true|
|[a, a, null]|[a, a, null]| null|
+------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same in pySpark 2.4?

Comment: You can try `F.size(F.array_intersect('look_for', 'look_in')) == F.size('look_for')`. But use with care, as it works in a different way. For null values the function will always return something. Also, duplicates inside arrays would return different results than the script above.